# does keycloak wildfly adapter care for "Issued At" Claim

Tags: jwt, wildfly, keycloak

I wonder if, keycloak wildfly adapter care for "Issued At" Claim.

So imagine, a keycloak standalone and a wildfly server have a small time difference, and keycloak creates a JWT token where iat (issued at) claim
seems to be a few milliseconds in future (at least in comparison to the time at the server running wildfly)  ...
What will happen? The token will be accepted or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token will be accepted, `iat` is used for the comparaison with the `not-before` property. By default `not-before` is set to 0 and `iat>not-before` and the token will be valid but `not-before` can be set to now (or future) and than the `iat` is needed to validate the token.